# Ask for FocusNavigationDirection.Last without actually moving there

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-4.0

This code:

```
this.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Last));
```

Will move the focus to the last control.

But is there a way to just ask what the last control is?  Without actually moving there?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Control.GetNextControl Method as it gives the next control forward or back in the tab order of child controls.